# Recovering python files after uninstalling Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, installation, anaconda, uninstallation

I had an issue with my computer so i had to reinstall my packages including python (Anaconda). I did not realise that when Anaconda gets uninstalled in the computer it deletes all files under `C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3` so i stupidly lost all python codes (how silly i should have been more careful). I am assuming there is no possibility of recovering the deleted python files but i wanted to ask anyway if there is a possibility to do so?

Many Thanks

Comment: You may be able to recover deleted files using a disk utility. In that case stop using the computer immediately to reduce the likelihood of overwriting the deleted files.This is more a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) really.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. i ll ask again the question under Super User. I know how to access the disk utility but don't know how to recover the files.